# Cannot suggest a synonym

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I have little problem regarding how to suggest tags.

For example in MySQL there are: [my-sql](/questions/tagged/my-sql),  [mysql-query](/questions/tagged/mysql-query), and [mysql-server](/questions/tagged/mysql-server) and it said those will be remapped to [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

So if I enter my-sql to suggest it, it says

> The suggested tag must be exist in the system before you can suggest it!

Even if I enter a new suggestion it shows me this message.

How can I suggest a tag?

Comment: why would you suggest a tag as a synonym while it already is one?

Comment: i was asking on how to suggest

Answer (score 3):

**If you're getting that error message, the synonym you suggested isn't actually used by any question, therefore it doesn't exist.**

If it does exist, go to Tags, click on a Tag, at the top, it says **synonyms(x)**, click on that.

[image: suggest tag]

Then, at the bottom of that page, there is a "Suggest" box, type your suggestion into there:

[image: suggest tag 2]

Comment: From the question, it *seems* like the user already tried to suggest it, but just failed due to the status of the tag.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Check his last comment to his question :). I think he wants to know how to suggest.

Comment: i have already tried this , but as i said i got all the time this message

Comment: @user998158 Ah, the suggestion you make must already be used by at least one question